# Element position changes in html after using javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a code where i will be displaying more than three graphs at a time. I have used div tag and tables to separate each graphs and display everything one below the other. But when i try to use a javascript function to just view one graph and hide the rest. The position of the graph changes. The graph will be shown in an incomplete way.
It normally displays in the following way:http://i47.tinypic.com/or1d91.png
But when i use javascript function it is being displayed as:http://i48.tinypic.com/345zkeq.png

I am including the code below for javascript and html part:

```
    <script>
    hideAllDivs = function () {
  $("#uae").hide();
  $("#ksa").hide();
  $("#iran").hide(); 
  };

 handleNewSelection = function () {

 hideAllDivs();

 switch ($(this).val()) {
    case '1':
        $("#ksa").show();
    break;
    case '2':
        $("#uae").show();
    break;
    case '3':
        $("#iran").show();
    break;
 }
 };

 $(document).ready(function() {

 $("#view").change(handleNewSelection);

// Run the event handler once now to ensure everything is as it should be
handleNewSelection.apply($("#view"));

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center"><tr><td><select id="view">
<option value="">Overall</option>
<option value="1">KSA</option>
<option value="2">UAE</option>
<option value="3">IRAN</option>
</select>
</td></tr></table>
<div id="country">
<table align="center">
<tr><td style="width:800px;height:500px"><div id="container5" style="min-width: 400px;  height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:50px"></div></td>
<td><table style="border: solid thin #000"><th>Country</th><th>Risk Score</th><?php     foreach( $names4 as $n){
                   echo "<tr><td>";
                   echo $n[0];
                   echo "</td><td>";
                   echo $n[1];
                   echo "</td></tr>";}
                   ?></table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="ksa">
<table align="center">
<tr><td style="width:800px;height:500px"><div id="container2" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:50px"></div></td>
<td><table style="border: solid thin #000"><th>Username</th><th>Risk Score</th><?php  foreach( $names1 as $n){
                   echo "<tr><td>";
                   echo $n[0];
                   echo "</td><td>";
                   echo $n[1];
                   echo "</td></tr>";}
                   ?></table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="uae">
<table  align="center">
<tr><td style="width:800px;height:500px"><div id="container3" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:50px"></div></td>
<td><table style="border: solid thin #000"><th>Username</th><th>Risk Score</th><?php foreach( $names2 as $n){
                   echo "<tr><td>";
                   echo $n[0];
                   echo "</td><td>";
                   echo $n[1];
                   echo "</td></tr>";}
                   ?></table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="iran">
<table  align="center">
<tr><td style="width:800px;height:500px"><div id="container4" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:50px"></div></td>
<td><table style="border: solid thin #000"><th>Username</th><th>Risk Score</th><?php  foreach( $names3 as $n){
                   echo "<tr><td>";
                   echo $n[0];
                   echo "</td><td>";
                   echo $n[1];
                   echo "</td></tr>";}
                   ?></table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the div within the table, div = container 5, div container 2 , div contaier 3 etc. Your giving the table a width of 800px then within that your placing a div that gives you 400 px; , it is 100% NOT THE JAVASCRIPT, it is the calculated css